# Cannot push data from android to mysql on wamp: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Tags: android, wamp

I followed a couple of tutorials to scan barcodes using an android device. I now want to push the data to mysql as part of WAMP on my computer. The barcode scan works but pushing the data doesn't. Following is my code:

```
package com.someName.someName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

//Import Zxing classes
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

//Imported based on tutorial instruction
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class ScanBarcodeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Added as per tutorial instruction
    private Button scanBtn;
    private Button updateBtn;
    private TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;

    String scanContent;
    String scanFormat;

    //Done on own
    public Button btnUpdateDatabase;
    jsonParser jsonParser = new jsonParser();

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String url_create_scan_record = "http://IP.IP.IP.IP:3306/someName_connect/create_scan_record.php";

    public String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_barcode);

        // Added as per tutorial
        scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ScanBarcode);
        updateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.UpdateDatabaseButton);
        formatTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
        contentTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_content);

        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View a){
            //creating new record in background thread

                UpdateDatabaseMethod(a);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.scan_barcode, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Added as per tutorial
    public void scanBarcodeMethod(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.ScanBarcode) {
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();

        }

    }

    // retrieve scan result
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //we have a result
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
            contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);

        }
        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }   


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Update database method
        public void UpdateDatabaseMethod(View view){

            //Log.d("Test Print", btnUpdateDatabase.toString());

//          //Button click event
//          btnUpdateDatabase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
//                  
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View a){
//          //creating new record in background thread
//          new CreateNewRecord().execute();
//          }
//      }); 

            new CreateNewRecord().execute();

    }

            /**Background Async Task to create new record
             **/

            class CreateNewRecord extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
                /**Show progress dialog before starting background thread
                 **/


//              @Override
                protected void onPreExecute(){
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    //Unsure of this line. Different activity in tutorial
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ScanBarcodeActivity.this);

                    pDialog.setMessage("Creating Record...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

                /**Creating Record
                 **/
                protected String doInBackground(String...args){
                    String scanFormat1 = scanFormat.toString();
                    String scanContent1 = scanContent.toString();
//                  String DeviceID = deviceIDView.getText().toString();
//                  String OperatorID = operatorIDView.getText().toString();

                    Log.d("format: ",scanFormat1);
                    Log.d("content: ",scanContent1);

                    //Building Parameters. Need to check that the order of parameters is correct
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scanFormat", scanFormat1));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scanContent", scanContent1));
//                  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceIDView", DeviceID));
//                  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("operatorIDView", OperatorID));


                    //getting JSON object
                    //Note that create record url accepts POST method
                    JSONObject json = com.someName.someName.jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_scan_record, "POST", params);

                    //Check log cat for response
                    Log.d("Create Response",json.toString());

                    //Check for success tag
                    try{
                        String TAG_SUCCESS= "success";
                        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                        if (success==1){
                            //Successfully created record
                            //Unsure of this line. Different activity in tutorial
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateNewRecord.class);
                            startActivity(i);

                            //closing this screen
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            //failed to create record
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }
                    /**Dismiss progress dialog after completing background task
                     **/
                    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
                        //dismiss the dialog once done
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
        }
```

The logcat is:
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364): Process: com.someName.someName, PID: 19364
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    at com.someName.someName.ScanBarcodeActivity$CreateNewRecord.doInBackground(ScanBarcodeActivity.java:169)
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    at com.someName.someName.ScanBarcodeActivity$CreateNewRecord.doInBackground(ScanBarcodeActivity.java:1)
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-13 20:12:37.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19364):    ... 4 more

Comment: i dont see where you call your asyncTask and i dont see where you call startActivityForResult to do scanning